# Add Tabbar Item Image from one UIImage issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbaritem

I'm Newbie in Swift.

I have a question.

When I add Tabbar Item image from one UIImage, then Nothing show up.

Although, Not in Tabbar Item, Image appear well and image that load from asset to tab bar item works well.

I already resize that thing, and not in tab bar, that resized image load well.

So, I'm so confused how to do that.

Here is my codes

This is load from Facebook profile picture

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "email, id, name, picture"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

        if err != nil {
            print("FBLogin Error: \(err)")
            return
        }
        print(result!)

        let dd = result as! [String : AnyObject]

        let test = (dd["picture"]!["data"]!! as! [String: AnyObject])["url"]

        let url = URL(string: test as! String)
        let data_picture = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        var temp_img = UIImage()
        temp_img = UIImage(data: data_picture!)!

        temp_tabbar_profile = self.resizeImage(image: temp_img, targetSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```

temp_tabbar_profile is UIImage

And This is resize code.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

This is set tab bar image code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tabBarItems = tabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem]

    tabBarItems[0].selectedImage = temp_tabbar_profile
    tabBarItems[0].image = temp_tabbar_profile
    tabBarItems[0].title = ""

}
```

When I run app, then just gray picture appeared.
When I load this temp_tabbar_profile in other view's image view.image,
loaded well!!!

I don't know what is wrong.

Thank you for reading my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `tabBarItems[0].image = temp_tabbar_profile.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`. Or the UITabBar will display your image in a abstract way.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean.         tabBarItem = tabBarItems[0] this is right?

Comment: i am sorry i somehow read toolbar. -.- Have you checked if it works with a different Image maybe one that doesn't have to be resized?

Comment: Oryour could try `tabBarItems[0].image = temp_tabbar_profile.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`. I have tried it with a small image and it works fine. Maybe it the image is corrupted while you resize it.

Comment: Yeah I solved by using renderingMode(.alwaysOriginal). Thank you @Adarkas2302 !

Comment: I have edited this answer please accept it if it helped.